# Swiper in modal window

Tags: javascript, swiper.js

I init Swiper slider in modal window.

```
var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper', {
            loop: true,
            autoplay: 3000,
            speed: 1500,
            prevButton: '.prev',
            nextButton: '.next',
            observer: true,
            observeParents: true,
            slidesPerView: 3,
            spaceBetween: 30,
            breakpoints: {
                640: {
                    slidesPerView: 1,
                    spaceBetween: 30,
                }
            }
        });
```

Related HTML:

```
<a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#certificates__modal">
    <div class="blue-button">
        <span class="text">
            modal
        </span>
    </div>
</a>

<section id="certificates__modal" class="certificates__modal modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="certificates__swiper swiper-container">
                    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
                        <div class="swiper-slide">
                            <div class="background-image" style="background: url('img/certificates/01.jpg') 50% no-repeat;"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="swiper-slide">
                            <div class="background-image" style="background: url('img/certificates/02.jpg') 50% no-repeat;"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="swiper-slide">
                            <div class="background-image" style="background: url('img/certificates/03.jpg') 50% no-repeat;"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="prev-slide-button"></div>
                <div class="next-slide-button"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

When my display is less than equaly 576px, photos automatically have width 0. I have a madness with it. I even don't know, where find this trouble... Help somebody, please. Maybe somebody had the same problem

Comment: Can you also post the related HTML?

Comment: As @DanielD said please post the related HTML. Don't just post a link and instructions where to look.

Comment: Sorry, I correct my question

Answer (score 0):

There was a trouble with "container" block. I don't know, what about the critical point of bootstrap and swiper, but excluding helped me